# query session not working when invoking cmd.exe from console app

Tags: cmd, wow64

query session does not work when using Any CPU or X86 target Platform , but works when using X64 platform.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","/k query session");
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = info;
    proc.Start();
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Is there a way I can make this work when I set it to Any CPU with Default Processor architecture set to X86?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily overcome by using pinvoke.net. Here is the solution

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{
    IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", "/k query session");
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = info;
    proc.Start();
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
}
```

Works perfectly on Any CPU, X86 and X64 target platforms

Answer (score 2):

Your computer has two versions of cmd.exe:

- c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
- c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe

When you run your application with Any CPU or x86, you are invoking the syswow64 version. This version of cmd.exe does not have the `query` command:

```
c:\Windows\SysWOW64>cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\Windows\SysWOW64>query
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To make it work in Any CPU or x86, make sure that you invoke the system32 version of cmd.exe

Comment: That is correct, Thanks for the reply but is there a alternative to query.exe which can be the solution for this problem??

Comment: @virali you could try `qwinsta` which is equivalent to `query session`

Comment: @wmz `qwinsta` is also not available in SysWOW64 cmd.exe

Comment: @wmz I tried both query user & qwinsta and getting the "not recognised as internal or external command". Any ideas for resolving this strange issue?