# Batch file that remotely checks logged in users generates empty text file when called from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I've got a simple C# Windows Form with a button that executes a batch file to remotely check the currently logged in user(s) of a VM and then dump the results to a text file.

The problem is that whenever the batch file executes it creates an empty text file. Generally speaking, if I run the batch file through file explorer it takes about 3 seconds to run the query and dump the text file (with proper contents), however, through C# it generates the empty text file in a little over a second.

C#:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String bat = @"BATCHFILE.bat";

        try
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = bat;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString()); }
    }
```

Batch file:

```
query user /server:server_name > SAVEPATH.txt 
exit
```

What am I not including in order for this to work?

---

Edit: editing the batch file to not perform a network query and just echoing "hello world" to text file does work properly. So, it's definitely something w.r.t. the network activity.

Comment: Check the working directory parameter.

Comment: Directories are accurate. I stripped them just before copying/pasting into this post. Without calling from C# the batch file working properly, and when calling from C# the text file is generated, it's just empty.

Comment: Try with `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`

Comment: @dcg Still empty.

Comment: Is your batch file being run elevated as administrator? _which is a requirement for `query user`!_

Comment: Do you really need to run a batch file to query user information after all?

Comment: @aschipfl When it's going to be scaled up to report on 17 VMs with 10-12 people bouncing around on them and needing to know if a given VM is actively being used, yes.

Comment: @Charles Did you try redirect both outputs to `SAVEPATH.txt`? e.g. `query user /server:server_name 1> SAVEPATH.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @Charles And you should also check out this: [query session not working when invoking cmd.exe from console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24271501)